# OpenCV subtitle remove smoothly

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, inpainting

I use OpenCV inpaint func to remove subtitle from image. But output image always have a transparent thread. How to fix it? I want output image more smoothly.

```
def inpaint_remove(image: 'cv2.typing.MatLike',
                   chunks: 'typing.Iterable[Rect]') -> 'cv2.typing.MatLike':
    image_h, image_w, image_c = image.shape
    assert image_c == 3, 'input must be BGR'

    mask = np.zeros((image_h, image_w), dtype=np.uint8)
    for chunk in chunks:
        mask[chunk.top - 10:chunk.bottom + 10, chunk.left - 10:chunk.right + 10].fill(255)
    return cv2.inpaint(image, mask, 5, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
```

source image:

[image: source image]

output image:

[image: output image]

Subtitle remove smoothly.

Comment: that "seam" going the length of the masked area? pick a different inpainting method instead of `INPAINT_TELEA`.

Comment: you mean "INPAINT_NS"? i try this flags params, also have that "seam"

Comment: you can also try `cv.xphoto.inpaint`, which would require `opencv-contrib-python` instead of plain `opencv-python`. there is some documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/d2f/tutorial_xphoto_inpainting.html